# Twitter bootstrap row horizontal scroll issue in container fluid

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am having an issue with negative margin for row in bootstrap 3.3.5

Even though I use container-fluid to wrap the rows, I am still getting a horizontal scrool bar due to negative margins.

Can be seen here http://cez.varle.cz/

I tried to look for solutions, but nothing works for me.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try .container-fluid{ overflow:hidden;}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After checking your code, it seems that you are missing a `container-fluid` for a row in the code. When I wrapped the code, I could get rid of the negative margin which is generating the scroll bar.

**Before wrapping:**

Horizontal Scroll bar due to negative margin. Check the selected element in Firebug.

[image: Before Wrapping]

**After wrapping:**

Horizontal Scroll bar removed.

[image: After Wrapping]

Answer (score 1):

**Michal** Hi there. Your problem is coming from the div section around line 500 in your code.
Look for this `<div class="hp-grey-bg">`
if you comment out from this div down to the close of this div which is around line 553, you will see that the scroll bar goes away.

Look to see what is within this beit your css that is giving you a issue here.

Hope this helps.

**Added**

It was your **Map** in this block of code.
Just by add `col-xs-6` to the `row` on line 539 made it work.
You will also need to change the div class below this `row` like this.

```
<div class="row col-xs-6">
<div class="col-md-12 map">
<div class="mapa-bg"><img src="http://cez.varle.cz/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/mapa.jpg" alt="" /><br />

<p class="mapa-text"><strong>Adresa:</strong><br />
Bolzanova 1 <br />
110 00, Praha 1<br />
<strong>+420 224 221 476</strong><br />
office@akcilinkova.cz</p>

</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```